# Why do I ever need to point the Array constructor from another source and why can't I call toString() directly on array objects?

Tags: javascript

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

var _Array = window.frames[window.frames.length-1].Array;

var arr = new _Array(1,2,3);

typeof arr; //'object'
arr instanceof Array; //false
```

I have 3 question about this code:

1. Object.prototype appears on the proto chain of both _Array and Array prototypes but Array and _Array are not in the same chain and because of that (arr instanceof Array) returns false?
2. I want to understand what's exactly going here, these are my thoughts:
   _Array points to the same constructor as where "windows.iframe[...].Array" points, then we create an instance of _Array, its **proto** points to Array.prototype, and *Array.prototype.proto* points to Object.prototype. So, both _Array and Array are constructors of array objects, which are inherited from Object.prototype. So, why do I need to call toString() directly from Object.prototype in order to get "[object Array]" on _Array and Array objects? When I call it like this: arr.toString() I get an empty string and when I call
   Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) I get "[object Array]". Why is that?
3. Can someone explain please why do I ever need to point to the Array constructor from another source? in this code _Array points to the same constructor as where "windows.iframe[...].Array" points to. Why is it useful?

Comment: Do not post code as pictures.

Comment: "*Object.prototype appears on the proto chain of both _Array and Array prototypes*" - Nope. `typeof` has nothing to do with the prototype chain. You will find that  `arr instanceof Object` will yield `false` as well. You can however do `arr instanceof window.frames[window.frames.length-1].Object`

Comment: @Bergi _Array and Array both point to the same constructor. So _Array objects are actually created from Array.prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Array` is *just* a data structure with behavior; there are many array implementations, and you can implement your own as well.

> 1. I want to understand what's exactly going here...

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// Accessing a new type of Array
var _Array =
  window.frames[window.frames.length-1].Array;

// Instantiates new array of type "_Array" (declared in iframe)
var arr = new _Array(1,2,3); // [1,2,3]

// Shows the type of arr variable
typeof arr; //-> 'object'

// Asserting that the "arr" instance is not in an instance of type "Array" (native Javascript type), rather it is of the type declared in the iframe
arr instanceof Array; //-> false
```

> 2. (...) Why is it useful?

Please note that this code pretty useless on its own (it is an example snippet), its probable goal is to show

- basic type-related operations in Javascript
- possibility for iframes to hold data, such as new types (`Array`)

Comment: 1. Is _Array points to the same function constructor as Array?  If so, _Array points to a native JavaScript type(Array), 2. Why can't I call arr.toString() directly instead of Object.prototype.toString.call(arr)?

Comment: @MorHaham You can easily find out by comparing `Array == _Array`. The whole point of the example is to demonstrate that you can have multiple native Array constructors

Comment: @MorHaham "*Why can't I call arr.toString() directly*" - of course you can. Try it, it works! The whole point of using `Object.prototype.toString.call(x)` in a *generic* method for *any* `x` is that `x` might include things like `{toString() { return "rubbish"}}` where `x.toString()` does *not* work.

Comment: I see it false but don't understand this behavior. I learned that Javascript variables point to primitives and objects and not copy them.

Comment: @Bergi When I call arr.toString() I get an empty string and when I call Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) I get "[object Array]".

Comment: @MorHaham Ooops, I totally forgot that `Array.prototype` does have a custom `toString` method, indeed that's just like the `x` in my example - `[].toString()` does not call the `Object` method that you actually want here.

Comment: @MorHaham I don't see what you think is copied here?

Comment: @Bergi  If _Array points to the Array constructor, an _Array object is also inherited from Array.prototype. so arr isinstanceof Array should return true.

Comment: @MorHaham No, that's not what I said. `Array` points to *an* Array constructor, whereas `_Array` points to a *different* Array constructor. With its own prototype, with its own everything - it is from a different world: the iframe which has a separate set of all globals.

Comment: @Bergi What's exactly the "different" Array constructor? the regular Array constructor but in a new frame. The fact they are in separate frames does mean that they are on different chains but they are both point to the old good Array constructor, so instanceof checks spots in memory and not the Array identity?

Comment: @MorHaham No, they do not point to "the good old Array constructor". They point to different function objects (that might do the same). Think of multiple tabs: each has its own JS environment, so that if you modify a native object in one of them it does not affect the others. It's the same for frames. `instanceof` checks for prototype inheritance.

Comment: @Bergi I think that I got it, the instanceof checks for prototype inheritance in the current call object(the current frame), and _Array points to an Array constructor in a different call object(frame)? I am not familiar with frames and it is a new concept for me to know that call objects can interact with each other, I mean that _Array can point to a constructor in other frame.